# Floating images are not at the same height on relative position

Tags: html, css, css-position

I need a set of icons grouped under a div to appear to the right of my logo (which is located on the top-left corner). I need the logo and all icons to have a position of relative. I am using `float:left` for both divs, but the second div (the group of icons) appears below the logo and not to its right. I have also tried grouping them under an unordered list and input `style="float:left"` as HTML, but it does not work either.

Here is the CSS:

```css
div.container {
  width: 1111px;
}

#parent {
  display: flex;
}

.logo {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
}

#icons {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.all-icons {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 15px;
  display: table-cell;
}

.all-icons img {
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  max-height: 77px;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 15px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="parent">
      <div class="logo"> <img src="http://placehold.it/77" width="27%" height="27%"> </div>
      <div id="icons" style="float:left" class="all-icons">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/77" width="389" height="317">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/77" width="451" height="317">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/77" width="427" height="317">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/77" width="837" height="317">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/77" width="594" height="317">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you look for?

```css
div.container {
  /* width: 1111px; */
}
#parent {
  display: flex;
}
.logo img {
  margin: 15px;
}
.all-icons {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.all-icons img {
  margin: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div id="parent">

    <div class="logo">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/77/f00" alt="">
    </div>

    <div id="icons" class="all-icons">
      
      <img src="http://placehold.it/77" alt="">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/77" alt="">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/77" alt="">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/77" alt="">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/77" alt="">

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

If you can't use `flex`, try `display: table`

```css
div.container {
  /* width: 1111px; */
}
#parent {
  display: table;
}
.logo {
  display: table-cell;
}
.all-icons {
  display: table-cell;
}
.logo img {
  margin: 15px;
}
.all-icons {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.all-icons img {
  margin: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div id="parent">

    <div class="logo">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/77/f00" alt="">
    </div>

    <div id="icons" class="all-icons">
      
      <img src="http://placehold.it/77" alt="">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/77" alt="">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/77" alt="">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/77" alt="">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/77" alt="">

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am looking to get the grey boxes directly on the right of the red box.

Comment: @Renzo Without the white space between?

Comment: No, preferably still equal margins between all the elements. @LGSon

Comment: @Renzo No space between the red box and the first gray box?

Comment: Yes a space between them as well @LGSon

Comment: @Renzo But that is how it looks now?? ... The gray boxes to the right of the red and space between them all

Comment: I actually see the red box on the top row and the grey boxes ordered below it, all indented to the left of the page @LGSon

Comment: @Renzo But they are in one row now ... are you referring to my snippet above or your own code? ... what browser do you use?

Comment: I am using your snippet above. I tried Full page to make sure. I'm on Safari now. I still see them on two rows

Comment: @Renzo Then that browser doesn't support `flex` ... updated my answer with a 2:nd sample, does that one work?

Answer (score 0):

Add `#icons { text-align: right; }`, i think this will help you.

please do remove `#parent { display: flex;}` and also remove `#icons { width: 100% }`

Comment: It aligns the icons to the right of the page, but they are still placed below the logo and not right by it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks in line to me (see below image) however the margins/padding make it look like it's below and to the right.

[image: Margins and Padding]

Other things which may prove useful having seen your code:

- `display: inline-table`
- http://flexboxgrid.com/
- remembering to keep CSS files as small as possible, not as comprehensive as possible to make it easy to find and fix things

Answer (score 0):

Your image of logo class not in center of its parent. Add

`text-align: center;
 margin: auto;`

into you .logo class